# recording audio in swift and passing the recorded audio to the next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am trying to record Audio, and pass the recorded audio, to the next view controller.  Here is my code for recording Audio

```
class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var recording: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!

var recordedAudio : RecordedAudio!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   // enables record button 
    // hides the stop button
    recordButton.enabled = true
    stopButton.hidden = true

}
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    //Shows recording label
    recording.hidden = false

    //diabling record button
    recordButton.enabled = false
    stopButton.hidden = false

    //Filepath Creation
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"
    let recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)+".wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    println(filePath)

    // Recording Session

    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)

    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()

}



func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    // ToDo create recorded audio file
    if(flag)
    {   recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()

        recordedAudio.filepathURL = recorder.url

        recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent

    // ToDo Perform segue

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("stopRecording", sender: recordedAudio)
    }
    else {
        println("Recording was unsuccessfull")
        stopButton.hidden = true
        recordButton.enabled = true

    }
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue == "stopRecording") {

        let PlaySoundsVC:PlaySoundsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaySoundsViewController
        let data = sender as! RecordedAudio

        PlaySoundsVC.receivedAudio = data
    }
}


@IBAction func stopAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    // Hides recording
    recording.hidden = true
    audioRecorder.stop()
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    audioSession.setActive(false, error: nil)

}
}
```

My Model class is ,

```
import Foundation

class RecordedAudio : NSObject{

    var filepathURL :NSURL!
    var title : String!
}
```

Here is how My second viewcontroller catch the data and uses it,

```
    class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var receivedAudio: RecordedAudio!

    func rateplay (rtt : Float32) {
        audioPlayer.stop()

        audioPlayer.rate = rtt

        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0
        audioPlayer.play()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3")
//        {
//        // if path is there for mp3
//          let filepathurl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
//            
//          // println(receivedAudio.title)
//            
//        }
//        else {
//        println("Path is empty")
//        
//        }
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filepathURL, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.enableRate = true




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func playSlow(sender: UIButton) {
    // play sloooowllyyyyy
        audioPlayer.stop()

        audioPlayer.rate = 0.5

        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0

        audioPlayer.play()

    }
    @IBAction func playFast(sender: UIButton) {
       rateplay(1.5)

    }

    @IBAction func stopAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Untill I add the below code,

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filepathURL, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.enableRate = true
```

I was able to move to the second scene, which means, the audio is successfully recorded. But as soon as i access the data like "receivedAudio.filepathURL" I am getting the error,

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Figure out which is nil. Is it `receivedAudio` or `filePathURL`?

Comment: receivedAudio is a class of type RecordedAudio, so probably filepathURL should be empty i guess so.

Answer (score 0):

In the prepareForSegue function of the `RecordSoundsViewController` you need to write `segue.identifier == "stopRecording"` as the condition.

Currently you have `segue == "stopRecording"`.

Happy Coding!